# pass php variables from one form to be submitted to database in another

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a pop up box which checks if the user is signed in or not.  If he is, I'm echoing out a small form which the user will press a button and it will submit to the DB.  The variables are displayed on the popup but when pressed submit, they do not pass to the submit php file.

```
$add_wish = "<form action='memWishList.php' method='post' id='memWishList'>
    <h3>Add this item to your Wish List?</h3><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='title' value='".$title."'>".$title."</input><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='link' value='".$link."'></input><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'/><button id='cancel'>
      Cancel</button>
</form>";
    echo $add_wish;
```

I want to pass the values title and link to be submitted to the DB.  Here's my memWishList.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  //get member id
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
  $link = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
  $mysql = "INSERT INTO wish_list (memNum, title, link, date) VALUES ('$memnum', \ 
      '$title', '$link', now())";
    $myquery = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, $mysql);}
```

Doing it this way, I only get the member id and the date inserted, not the title and the link.  What's the problem?  The reason why I'm echoing out this form is there's an if/else statement for logged in users and non logged in.  Would be much easier to do it in html but can't...

DB: memnum(varchar), title(longtext), link(longtext), date(date).  I have other tables where long links and titles are inserted just fine as longtext.  They're coming from rss feeds.

Comment: show your database description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php): mysqli_real_escape_string function expect the string as 2nd parameter if you use a procedural approach. It could be i.e.:

```
$link = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connect, $_POST['link']);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it...for some reason it worked with only one parameter before...but that was when I was binding statements.  Anyway, still learning.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have some markup errors. Your hidden input tags should look like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='link' value="<?php echo $link ?>">
```

Update your HTML file to look like this and all of the values will be sent to the $_POST variable:

```
<form action='memWishList.php' method='post' id='memWishList'>
    <h3>Add this item to your Wish List?</h3><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='title' value="<?php echo $title ?>"><?php echo $title ?><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='link' value="<?php echo $link ?>"><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'/><button id='cancel'>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: My form is within php so everything is in quotes...since it's within php, putting value="<?php echo $link?>"> wouldn't work, would it?  The form is not within the body tags...it's within php tags and is being echoed out to the screen.

Comment: No they won't work, but you shouldn't output a form as a PHP string anyway. Replace your form with the one I provided and it'll work, or correctly update your form if you wish to keep the whole thing in a string.

Comment: I understand that's the proper way to do it but like I said in my initial question, the reason why I'm doing it this way is because I'm checking to see if the user is logged in or not.  If they are, I'm outputting the form.  If not, I'm showing a login form.  But it's all done within php because it's checking.  If there's a better way to do this, let me know.

Comment: Then replace `<input type='hidden' name='title' value="<?php echo $title ?>">` with the correct code. Use `<input type='hidden' name='title' value='".$link."'>` instead.

Comment: That's what I had to begin with.  My problem was the 2 parameters needed in the mysqli_escape function.  Thanks for the advice anyway.